# Numerical integration in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to compute the following integral in MATLAB GUI:

```
f(x) = a/(a+x^2)
```

---

When I input `a = 1`, this result shows up:

```
a^(1/2)*atan(x/a^(1/2))
```

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
 a = str2double(get(handles.anum, 'String'));     
 formula = sym(get(handles.enter_func, 'String'));       
 result = int(formula);       
 set(handles.int, 'String', char(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, `a` in `handles.enter_func` has nothing to do with `a` that you define in `handles.anum`. The symbolic integration is executed assuming the generic `a`. Therefore you get the generic result. To make substitution, you need to do use `subs` after integration:

```
result= subs(int(formula),a,str2double(get(handles.anum , 'String')));
```

The substitution would replace `a` with the value provided in `handles.anum`.